# Losing data on .Where(expression) to list()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

```
Func<View_Album_Search, bool> expressionAlbum = Al => Al.name.Contains(text) || Al.soundName.Contains(text) || Al.artist.Contains(text);

var query = view_Album_SearchRepository.Where(expressionAlbum); 

var b = query.Count(); (*Count = 1440*)
                        (*Lose data *)
var a = query.ToList(); (*Count = 154*)

           /***************************************************\

 public IEnumerable<TEntity> Where(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    }
```

MODEL

```
 public partial class View_Album_Search
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal id_album { get; set; }
    public string soundName { get; set; }
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public byte feature { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> album_date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> hits { get; set; }
    public string artist_twitter { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> feature_order { get; set; }
    public string video_url { get; set; }
}
```

I dont understand, if I do it on get all works fine.
*Aditional information*
On debug mode when he do .toList() he execute the exrpessionAlbum again

Comment: Your naming of Classes and variables makes it very confusing to try and work out what it going on. I wouldn't expect a repository to have a `Where` method. Might help to describe what data type `view_Album_SearchRepository` actually is

Comment: Thanks for attention, more information was added. @musefan

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider your design. You should use `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` in the first place. Further, do you really need repository classes that basically just duplicate linq methods? Note that a DbSet already is a basic repository.

Comment: I see when execute the query, I get all correctly result whitout CASE SENSITIVE, and in toList() he execute the expression again whit CASE SENSITIVE. Okay now I see the probllem but @Gert Arnold I think you right so I think I cant remove one of this types, if you show one better way, I cant realise one but I understand what do you want to say. thanks. But at moment I need to disable the CASE SENS on toList() or modify this design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Func<View_Album_Search, bool> expressionAlbum = Al => Al.name.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower()) || Al.artist.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower());
```